# French Quiz Not Working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have made a french quiz but it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quiz</h1>
<p id="one"></p>
<input id="aone" />
<br>
<a href="#" class="myButton" id="btn">Mark It</a>
<script>
var verbs = ["accompagner","aider","aimer","apporter","chanter","danser","coûter","écouter","étudier","fermer","jouer","laver","marcher","montrer","oublier","passer","penser","préparer","raconter","agir","bâtir","choisir","désobéir","finir","guérir","nourrir","obéir","punir","réfléchir","remplir","réussir","rougir","saisir","attendre","défendre","descendre","entendre","interrompre","perdre","rendre","répondre","rompre","vendre"];
var verb = verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)];
if(verb.slice(-2) == "er") {
var newverb = verb.substring(0, verb.length - 2);
newverb += "es";
}
if(verb.slice(-2) == "ir") {
var newverb = verb.substring(0, verb.length - 2);
newverb += "is";
}
if(verb.slice(-2) == "re") {
var newverb = verb.substring(0, verb.length - 2);
newverb += "s";
}
document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = verb;
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
if (document.getElementById("aone").value==newverb) { // Not Working.
alert("Correct");
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I have traced the problem to the final `if` statement not being true but I don't understand why.
All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with sample input/output so we know what this is supposed to do and what the output is. What is this thing supposed to do?

Comment: Downvotes probably from not giving a minimal test case (not my vote(s)). Most people would not know you want the French second person singular for the prompted infinitive, hence requests for expected correct input. And yes, it does work. Try putting in an `else { alert("incorrect"); `} statement so it always responds.

Answer (score 0):

Its really unclear what you are trying to do since it is in another language.

However, your conditional is working. I added a `alert()` so you can see what "newverb" is equal to.

If in the input field, you add the value that was alerted, the conditional will work.

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/q7k2ez2L/